# desktop small beep sound

Tags: windows-10

I have HP Elite 8200 Small Form Factor desktop with Samsung SSD and Windows 10.

Recently it makes faint beep sound while the computer is turned on and I'm using it. It beeps twice quickly, and these two beeps are repeated infinitely.

(This is NOT beeping at startup, but noise during ordinary use)

What is the reason of this small beeping and how can I remove it?

ADDED:
It is high-pitched noise from the graphic card (AMD Radeon HD 6350).

I have noise even when the computer is idle.

Comment: WILD GUESS: Is the pc overheating, or more subtle, the fan speed sensor disconnected/broken? This can make the computer go hipocondriac and think it's going to overheat. Some BIOS let you see fan speed in a status section, or you could use a monitor app. This was causing constant (spaced out) beeping for me once, but it wasn't an hp.

Comment: Is it a high-pitched noise from the graphics card or beeping?

Comment: @TheKB I think it's not beeping but a high-pitch noise. And it's not exactly from graphic card, but from somewhere on the mainboard near the graphic card

Comment: Does it sound like [this?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsMXotF33mU)

Comment: @TheKB I cannot hear the noise from the Youtube video.. My noise was not a continuous one, but intermittent (every 30~60 sec) noise.